# How to add custom python 'self' syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: python, vim

I know how to turn on the custom syntax highlighing when editing python files

like:

```vi
:syn keyword Keyword self
```

However, It is annoying because I need to put the code every time.

I want to just edit .vimrc file.

How to do it?

Comment: put it in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
Making a syntax file is too difficult for me. That's too complex. sorry about my knowledge.

Comment: See: [How can I fix “missing” syntax highlighting for Python keywords such as “self”?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8772/51).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a command that you run every time when you open a particular filetype, you can use autocommands ([`:help autocmd-intro`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd%2dintro)).

In this particular case, you want to run some extra syntax code, so it makes sense to listen for the `Syntax` event of the `python` filetype ([`:help Syntax`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#Syntax)
):

```
augroup python_syntax_extra
  autocmd!
  autocmd! Syntax python :syn keyword Keyword self
augroup END
```

Putting this in your `.vimrc` should do the trick. The `augroup` stuff is only to ensure the autocommands in this group ("python_syntax_extra") don't get run twice ([`:help :augroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3aaugroup)).

Alternatively, you can put this in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` to organize common python settings. If you do that, you probably don't need the autocmd dance, even:

```
autocmd! Syntax <buffer> :syn keyword Keyword self
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot..! I think this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this simply by putting this line into `.vimrc`

```
match Keyword /self/
```

Comment: Can you provide your `.vimrc` (after added this line)?

Comment: Umm..I have downloaded `.vimrc` which is choosen Python from [vim-bootstrap](http://www.vim-bootstrap.com/)

And I deleted only `colorcolumn` line.

Answer (score 2):

While @AndrewRadev's solution works, there's actually a built-in extension mechanism for syntax scripts via the `:help after-directory`.

Just put the syntax extensions into `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`; this will be automatically sourced *after* the built-in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim`, and extend it:

```
syn keyword pythonStatement self
```

This is much simpler than using a filetype plugin to define a hook into the `Syntax` event.

Answer (score 1):

My solutions is not the best because I change Vim internal files but it works for me and was the quickest solution. I simply added the keyword `self` into the file `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim` which looks like:

```
syn keyword pythonStatement self
```